# Beautifully Autoscrolling the Page, Plus the "Spring" Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, touch

I would like to implement touch screen auto scrolling on my website.  Examples of which can be seen in the interfaces Ubuntu and Windows 8.

Ubuntu:

[image]

Windows 8:

[image]

If you make a sharp scroll down the page, it will continue to scroll after you let go and gradually slow. And if the scrolling has reached the lower or upper limit, the page kind of "springs". I think this is a very interesting, and I am wondering how to implement it on an HTML page. Are there are ready-made solutions?

Comment: You can use this: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html If you would like to take a shot at implementing it. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, however.

Answer (score 0):

Does this look something like what you are looking for?
http://scripterlative.com/files/dragscroll.htm
It may not fit perfectly, but you might be able to customize it the way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use scroll.js. It has fantastic scrolling functionality. Use it, and you'll automatically get the sprint effect also.